# Making multiple lines as single lines

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have below 4 lines:

```
EXTRACT    ETEST  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING  
Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST  Initialized   2016-03-31 06:25   Status STOPPED 
Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 02:21:09 ago)
```

All I want to make them into 2 lines like below:

```
EXTRACT    ETEST  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST  Initialized  2016-03-31 06:25   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 02:21:09 ago)
```

Which I am able to make with `cat /tmp/glog.lst|xargs -n 14`:

```
EXTRACT    ETEST  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST  Initialized  2016-03-31 06:25   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 02:21:09 ago)
```

But row1 has 14 fields, row2 has 13 fields.

The issue was row2 has Initialized   vs "Last Started"

I want to make a row with less than 14 columns to 14 cols installing dummy columns with or "N"(or) something so it will have 14 cols that way i can process my script easily.

I want to make it finally

```
EXTRACT    ETEST  Last Started  2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST  Initialized N 2016-03-31 06:25   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 02:21:09 ago)
```

This is what I need

```
$ awk '{ if (FNR%2==1) tmp=$0; else print tmp,$0 }'  /tmp/gglog.lst
EXTRACT    ETEST1  Initialized 2016-03-20 20:56   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST2  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST3  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST1  Last Started 2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:02 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST0  Last Started 2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:05 ago)
```

Now I want to take out column values of Initialized/Last/Started  so that it will come this way

```
EXTRACT    ETEST1  2016-03-20 20:56   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST2  2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST3  2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST1  2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:02 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST0  2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:05 ago)
```

or Can we break Initialized  to Init Now  ie. what ever the line we file work Initialized we want to break it into "Init Now"

```
EXTRACT    ETEST1  Init Now 2016-03-20 20:56   Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST2  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:04 ago)
EXTRACT    ETEST3  Last Started 2016-03-20 20:56   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:02 (updated 00:00:09 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST1  Last Started 2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:02 ago)
EXTRACT    PTEST0  Last Started 2016-03-29 08:46   Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:05 ago)
```

Comment: Would you mind making the line become space separator?

Comment: I suspect that what you are really looking for is a third column that can contain a string that includes spaces itself, rather than pad it out with a fake "N" column.  Are you sure there aren't tab separators in there.  If its all spaces yo may be able to apply patterns like `^(...........)(.......)(.............)` , etc, to pick out your columns.  But tab characters would mess that up

Comment: Does the original file have fixed-width columns? Is it tab-separated?

Comment: To check if the file is space or tab-delimited, try something like `head file | cat -A`.  If you see `^I` in the output, then it's tab-delimited.  That makes things easy, because none of your input lines have 14 fields (they just *look* like they do), they all have 13 tab-delimited fields.

Answer (score 0):

- To merge lines two by two:

  `awk '{ if(FNR%2==1) tmp=$0; else print tmp,$0 }' tmp/glog.lst`
- To replace `Initialized` with `Init Now`:

  `sed 's/Initialized/Init Now/' tmp/glog.lst`
- To do both, use a pipe to chain these:

  `awk '{ if(FNR%2==1) tmp=$0; else print tmp,$0 }' tmp/glog.lst | sed 's/Initialized/Init Now/'`

Comment: Thanks but that will not solve the problem

Comment: All i want is any number of lines should be having same columns that way i can compare and format them in next steps

Comment: am not able to post the code properly so i have update my main post

Comment: Awesome this works and solves my problems.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question, you can join consecutive lines like so using `sed`:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' /tmp/glog.lst
```

However, your column issue is really a separate question entirely.  The *best* solution to that is, **go upstream** to the tool that generates your `glog.lst` file and make it **use some sensible delimiter** rather than whitespace.

If that's completely impossible you may be able to work around it, but anything else will by necessity be a mere hack.